# iOS best practices with dynamic content

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, localization

I'm building an iOS with bilingual content, the user will be able to switch between languages at any point and the content will be updated to the selected language. What is the best way to keep track of all of my UIView components to facilitate the language switch?

The options I see are;

1. Make each element that could possibly change a property of my ViewController;
2. Give each element a tag and grab the elements with viewWithTag when required;
3. Throw out the whole container view and rebuild it from scratch.

To be honest none of these 3 options sound ideal, are there others options I haven't thought of? What is considered the best way to keep track of multiple elements?

Thanks,

**Edit 3 Mar 2014**

More details.

The app will have two versions of all the dynamic content, French and English. Only one language will be displayed at a time, but the user will be able to switch languages at any time and all of the displayed content should be updated.

App description.
The app is part of an instillation and will be run in kiosk mode with a landscape orientation. The left hand 2/3 of the screen will be a horizontal scroll view though which the the user can page though the content. When the user sees content that they wish to investigate further a vertical scrollview will slide up from the bottom and fill the right hand 1/3 of the screen. The user will then be able to page though details on the content. It is this dynamic detail content that I am currently working on changing according to language.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Could you provide some code?

Comment: This is a very useful tutorial for localization: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/localization-tutorial-for-ios

Comment: Thanks for the link to the tutorial it is very useful for localizing the static content. But at this point I am more concerned with the dynamic content. Basically all the dynamic content will have two language versions, only one will be displayed at a time but the user will be able to switch between the two. Will update question with a better description.

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do is subclass all "basic" components (`UILabel`, `UIButton` and others) and make them respond to a global, custom `NSNotification` sent by your controllers when the user switches a language, with the use of the global notification center (`[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]`). That way, anyone has a chance to update.

Comment: This sounds interesting, as I am still relatively new to iOS development I'm going to have to figure out how I would implement this.

Answer (score 1):

In a recent localisation attempt we just made every visible string an outlet and defined them as NSLocalizedString, then we have plist dictionaries for each language. It takes awhile to get all set up, but is relatively easy to maintain once it's there!

Not saying that's the best way, but that's what we did!

https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/

That link may help you! :)

Comment: Thanks for the link and the suggestion. This is a great way to handle localization of the static content, I'm just not sure how I would use this approach with dynamic content. I have updated the question with a more detailed description of what I'm trying to do.